# Как настроить автозапуск программы в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python, daemon

Для фоновой работы программы на сервере использую библиотеку [python-daemon](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/):

```
import daemon

from spam import do_main_program

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    do_main_program()
```

Но при перебоях в работе сервера программа перестаёт работать. Что можно использовать для демонизации с автозапуском? Ищу универсальное решение с возможностью запуска на сервере без админских прав и установки дополнительного ПО.

Comment: какая операционная система на сервере?

Comment: @Дмитрий ОС - Linux. Тестирую у себя на RaspberryPi.

Comment: рассматривали возможность отказаться от `python-deamon`. И использовать `systemd.service`. Была такая задачка, реализовал через venv и systemd, но это был ubuntu-сервер. Как это будет на Raspberry Pi не могу сказать

Comment: @Дмитрий для использования `systemd.servive` ведь нужны права администратора